# Give name to an array of Json in JSON.stringify

Tags: json, node.js

In PHP when I want to give a name to an array of json objects I use this line.

```
$json = json_encode(array("users" => $output));
```

And this variable would be printed like this.

```
{"users":[{"user_id":"1"}
```

But now, I'm building a project in Node.js and I need to give a name to an array, and I don't know how to do it, I'm printing data using this line:

```
 res.send(JSON.stringify(users, null, 4));

[ { "user_id": "1" }, { "user_id": "2" } ]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just build the object with "root" key `users` before `stringify`

```
res.send( JSON.stringify( { 'users': users } , null, 4) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send json directly specifying data points

```
res.json({ variablename : thevalue (in your case array)})
```

if more than one value, just follow the syntax

```
res.json({ variablename : thevalue1, variablename : value2)})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can something like this:

```
 {'users': JSON.stringify(users, null, 4)}
```

Comment: Please explain for voting down, would help me and others too.